# Kong SSL offloading to set reverse proxy from https to http

Tags: ssl, kong

I have a simple kong setup that i want to use to redirect https request to http using declarative kong.yml. I couldn't figure out how can i achieve this and would highly appreciate if someone could help me with that. Thanks in advance!

```
services:
- name: my-insecure-service
  protocol: http
  host: google.com
  port: 443
  routes:
  - name: my-insecure-service-route
    paths:
     - /abc
```

In the above case I want to route the request that lands on /abc to https://google.com:443. I am confused about defining the SSL certificate/key and how to route it from http to https (SSL offloading).

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate for your installation? Or how do you plan to get it?

Comment: yes i do, i have self-signed certificates that i plan to use for this

Comment: How the outside world connects to Kong is configured in *kong.conf*, not in *kong.yml*. Have a look at *proxy_listen*, *ssl_cert* and *ssl_cert_key*. In *kong.yml*, you can specify how Kong connects to upstream services. In the configuration, I would replace *protocol*, *host* and *port* with `url: https://www.google.com`

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. 
The idea here was to implement the reverse proxy that redirects https request to http, and the way you mentioned, it seems like to achieve this I would need to add SSL certificate, key etc to kong.conf.
What if I try to redirect an http request to https upstream, that's not possible either?

Comment: If you redirect from http to https, then the *kong.conf* configurations aren't needed. Just replace *protocol*, *host* and *port* with *url*.